# Tableau dynamic filter based on current selection

Tags: dynamic, filtering, tableau-api

Building a map that shows when certain company sites went into production.  The data has a "Start Year" column that is used to populate the map using the Playback feature.

Of course, an issue is that Tableau doesn't know that a site started in 2000 is still open today and should still be shown if the user is currently filtered to 2016.  As of right now, the report creator has simply checked the "Show History" box in the Start Year playback control box (picture below).

What I basically want to do is add a new column called End Year, and a dynamic filter that would reference the current year selected (call it "current year") by the playback slider and show all data records where the Start Year <= Current Year and End Year >= Current Year.

Is this possible?

[image: playback control]

Answer (score 0):

The end year column will solve your problems. Have separate end year/ start year columns, and create a 'current year' slider, that as you said will be limited by start/ end year for the company selected.

Comment: How will this interact with the Playback feature?